# IIS 7 Cors Ajax Soap request

Tags: javascript, ajax, soap, iis-7, cors

I have encountered a problem that I cant resolve.

I have some js (jquery) POST soap (over PHP) request code working on Apache with Cors enabled for calling HTTPS, and it worked fine.

I've migrated to IIS7, set response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods = POST`
```

and now strangly when sending

```
Content-Type: text/xml;
```

it is refused, but when sending a default

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

strangly I got the response (of course error response from Soap server but still, meaning that Cors works for this).

So the question is, if there is anything else to set in iis headers?  I tried to find an answer for a day but with no luck. My guess is it is about `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` but still I cant find a valid example.

Comment: our Java REST service has a `@Consumes` annotation that enforces the request content type. perhaps you have something along those lines that needs to be adjusted.

Comment: things is that it works fine when setting on the same domain, but problem occurs only when using cors (i gather data on some page and then send fingerprint over https to service). as said before worked smootly on apache, but i need to port it to iis 7. so my deduction is that its striclty connected to Access-Control-Allow-Headers,but i might be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the following header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

You may also have to put other headers in that list. The best way to figure out which headers to add is to inspect the Access-Control-Request-Headers header on the request, and see what values its asking for, and then echo those values in the response above.

The reason Content-Type needs to be included in this header is because you are asking for a non-standard value ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is a standard value).

Comment: omg, after reading through all of docs and stuf i thought more that allow headrs should hold a type not a name of header field. even dev mozilla example wasnt working. god bless u ;]