# xhr javascript PUT method

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, put

i need to send an xhr request in PUT method

this is my code :

```
function put(_url, _callback,_data){

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('PUT',_url);
  if (!xhr){
    throw new Error('CORS not supported');
  }
  $('.ajax-loading').show();

  xhr.send(_data);

  /*SUCCESS -- do somenthing with data*/
  xhr.onload = function(){
    // process the response.
    _callback(xhr.responseText);
    $('.ajax-loading').hide();
  };

  xhr.onerror = function(e){
    console.log(e);
    $('.ajax-loading').show();
  };
}
```

don't know why it doesn't works cause it doesn't pass data to the url i set.
while doing same function in POST method is ok!

any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers

Comment: @karim79 thanks but i posted a script if someone could help me , i just tryed and it doesnì't works

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043294/iis-7-cors-ajax-soap-request

Comment: @Andrew Leach  are you kidding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is correct, probably you have to check if you call that function in the code or something else. Try to cut & paste the function in console, then call it in the console.

In chrome works perfectly, even with a CORS server.

Tell me if it works.

Answer (score -2):

PUT methods do not work with standard browser HTTP methods. You will have to create a _method=put value into the POST variables to emulate the PUT request.